# How to executeScript for webRequest event onBeforeRequest in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Following Chrome Extension Manifest V3 rule I want to create an extension, that listens to particular network request and, for startes, just log them to the console of the currently opened tab (later I want to add custom script and styles to the page in the current tab).

For this I try to utilize chrome.scripting.executeScript.

When I implement the sample from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/examples/page-redder/manifest.json it works like expected for the chrome.action.onClicked listener.

As soon as I try to execute a script within the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest listener, this error pops up:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of
> scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional
> function callback): Error at parameter 'injection': Error at property
> 'target': Missing required property 'tabId'.
> at chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener.urls ()

Missing required property tabId? I assume it has to do with the lifecycle, but I cannot figure out what to do. This is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "matches":   [ "<all_urls>"]
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webNavigation",
        "management",
        "scripting"
      ]
  }
```

And this is my script, I just slightly modified the "redden"-example:

```
function reddenPage(url) {
    console.log(url);
}
  
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: reddenPage,
      args: [tab.url],
    });
},
  {urls: ["*://*.google.com/*"]},
    []);
```

Comment: 1) See the documentation for onBeforeRequest, its parameter is not a tab. 2) onBeforeRequest is the wrong event because it may take a long time for the request to get a response so your executeScript will run on the old page. 3) The ManifestV3 is completely broken for this use case because it can't run on page start so you will always see a flash of unstyled content. The only solutions in MV3 are a) to use the new chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts in Chrome 96 and newer, b) to use a content script declared in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm 1) right, thx, but that does not cause the error 2) sure, that's fine, but Ineed to track all requests, I will persists them, indeed  3) that's fine

Will try your a) / b) thanks!

Comment: FYI: Following the doc for I end up with a getTabId(); function, that google references, but I don't know how to implement it. If I try to build it by mymself with chrome.tabs.query, chrome.scripting seems to be unknown suddenly. Seems like it just should not work.

Comment: Sounds like you incorrectly placed it inside a content script e.g. inside the injected function, which by definition runs as a content script. Content scripts can't access most of `chrome` API.

Comment: uff..yes, after hours trying I'm now seeing that I was referencing the wrong file. This is...mind blowing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but the script from Github seems not work. This is how it works:

It's not only a couple of changed brackets, look at tab instead of (tab), but also tab.tabId instead of tab.id:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(tab => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
        {
        target: { tabId: tab.tabId },
        function: reddenPage,
        args: [details.url],
        },
        () => { console.log('ZZZ') });
    },  {
        urls: ['<all_urls>']
    });
```